# PHP Insert doesn't work anymore

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, insert, config

I've had my code working some time ago. Actually, I've asked for test and it still works in other pcs.

I formated mine, installed eclipse, wamp AND easyphp for double check and all the stuff, and now I have this issue.

It's a simple insert, a HTML with 2 textboxes, the table exists and it works directly by the MySQL workbench.

When I run the script via Browser, I wrote some echoes along the code, and it starts the ajax, calls the insert.php, and inside it it echoes before the require_once config.php

After that, no response at all.

I have put alert status and thown error in the error section in the ajax call, but nothing at all.

What may have happened to it ?

I use Windows, and I suspect of something deeper, but it can be an obvious mistake, I just have no idea where to search, as it works in other computers.

Here goes the code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>CRUD</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="" >
    Nome:
    <input type="text" name="nome" required />
    <br/>
    Tipo:
    <input type="text" name="tipo" required />
    <br/>


    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="save" id="sub"/> 
</form>

<script src="script/jquery-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script/ajaxInclude.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myForm').submit(function(){
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "DAO/insert.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function( data )
        {
            alert( data );
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
});
```

config.php

```
<?php

echo "DENTRO DO CONFIG";

define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'wms');
define('PORT', '3306');
define('USER', 'root');
define('PASS', '');

$dsn = 'mysql:host='.HOST.'; port='.PORT.'; dbname='.DB_NAME;

try {
$bd = new PDO($dsn, USER, PASS);
//  $bd->setAttribute(PDO::ATT_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Houve algum erro no Banco de Dados';
}

?>
```

insert.php

```
<?php

echo "FORA DO INSERT";

require_once('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    echo "DENTRO DO INSERT, SUBMIT POSTED";

 $nome = $_POST['nome'];
 $tipo = $_POST['tipo'];

 $sql =  'INSERT INTO produto(id, nome, tipo, criado_em) ';
 $sql .= ' VALUES (NULL, :nome, :tipo, NOW())';

 try {

    echo "DENTRO DO TRY";
    $query = $bd->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindValue(':nome', $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':tipo', $tipo, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if($query->execute()){
        echo "Dados inseridos com sucesso";
    }else{
        echo "Falha na insercao de dados";
    }

 } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
 }
 die();
}
?>
```

Comment: Please show some code - impossible to help otherwise.

Comment: @Luke Peterson there you go !

Comment: Do you see anything in your console.log() ?  Try to remove the try/catch block - does it work then?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I removed all the try/catches in the code, and firebug doesn't tell me anything.

I just get the echo before the require_once, this : echo "FORA DO INSERT";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On insert.php, change:

> if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

for

> if(isset($_POST['nome']) && isset($_POST['tipo'])){

Comment: and always check what's in $_POST.
`echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);`